# Div slides up and then down again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code display columns that slide down (the `.select-plan-details` div) when pressing `.select-plan-buy` (the other columns, if open, slide up).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="select-plan-container">

<div class="select-plan-column">
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-buy-starter">
  </div>
  <div class="select-plan-details select-plan-details-starter">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="select-plan-column">
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-buy-level">
  </div>
  <div class="select-plan-details select-plan-details-level">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="select-plan-column">
  <div class="select-plan-buy select-plan-buy-levels">
  </div>
  <div class="select-plan-details select-plan-details-levels">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
  jQuery(".select-plan-buy").click(function () {
    jQuery('.select-plan-column .select-plan-details').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).next(".select-plan-details").slideToggle();
  });
```

Right now when I press `.select-plan-buy` again (when `.select-plan-details` is already open), it slides up and then down again (the current column). How can I do it so it slides up properly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
 jQuery('.select-plan-column .select-plan-details').not(jQuery(this).next(".select-plan-details")).slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".select-plan-buy").click(function () {
    var objDetail=$(this).next(".select-plan-details");
    $('.select-plan-column .select-plan-details').not(objDetail).slideUp();
    objDetail.slideDown();
  });
```